# How can run a batch file after running a software?

Tags: batch-file, templates, powerpoint

for using the latest version of our templates, I want to copy the templates from our server to the user's local machine. but I want the templates will be copied to the local machine when the PowerPoint load and runs. I created a batch file to copy templates from server to local machine and I am looking for a way to run automatically this batch file after each time PowerPoint running.

Comment: If you want to execute some instruction arbitrarily after some process is started, just code a watchdog software to check if "POWERPNT.exe" is running every n milliseconds, and if it is, execute the batch instructions afterwards.

Comment: @Nastor thanks for your response. is there another way to use the Windows features to do this purpose? here we have a limitation to use new programs and software.

Comment: You can use something like common shell commands like "tasklist | findstr 'POWERPNT.exe' " to check if process is running.

Comment: @Nastor is it possible to use Image File Execution Options in the registry?

Comment: I don't know why you need to copy the files from the server to the local machine, but using Office's built-in Workgroup Templates feature, you can open templates from a network share. Here' more information: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/01/shared-workgroup-templates/

Comment: Is it really necessary to copy the templates whenever PPT runs? I'd think it would be sufficient to copy them whenever the user logs in, in which case a few lines in a login script should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I convert batch file to exe file that first copy templates to a local machine then run PowerPoint.exe.
with that method, my problem has been solved and it works fine.